# Internet not working after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, 16.04

I've recently upgraded my ubuntu version from 14.04 to 16.04. Now none of my internet connection work (neither ethernet or wifi), although both are recognized in the 'network connections' panel. I verified that both work with other devices.

I've searched for previous post here but none of them helped me. Some introduced slightly different problems (e.g., networks are not recognized in the panel / only wifi doesn't work etc.), or solutions that require `sudo apt-get` installations that use packages from the web, which I obviously can't download.